Checkbox only pick up current page in datatable
i got issue with my datatable checkboxes submission , when i debug at controller laravel , it only shows 10 values which is current page , each page display 10 row
here is my code
var DT = $('#table-data-notice').DataTable(config);
$('#hantar').on('click', function(){
    if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
        swal('Amaran', 'Sila pilih sekurang-kurangnya satu notis', 'warning');
        return false;
    }

    var $form = $('#verify-form');
    var params = DT.$('input').serializeArray();
    
    $.each(params, function(){ 
        if(!$.contains(document, form[this.name])){
        // If checkbox is checked
            if(this.checked){
                // Create a hidden element 
                $form.append(
                $('<input>')
                    .attr('type', 'hidden')
                    .attr('name', this.name)
                    .val(this.value)
                );
            }
        }
    });

    swal({
        title: "Anda pasti?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: '{!! __('Ya') !!}',
        cancelButtonText: '{!! __('Tidak') !!}'
    },
    function(confirmed){
        if (confirmed) {
            $('#verify-form').removeAttr('data-success');
            $('#verify-form').submit();
        }
    });
});

It should take all checked accross pages

It seems like his will work for you : Checkboxes only work on first page - Datatables,rails

I think the other page rows and checkboxes are hidden, those will not picked, you need write hidden values to find var hiddenCheckboxes = $('input:checkbox:hidden');
